# Google sheet script to search and retrieve Gmail data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've started a script that matches an email address in Col D with Gmail and writes the last message date in Col E. I'd like that script to repeat row by row - now it only writes to Row 2 (newbie question - sorry).

I'd also like to search for data in addition to "from". I'd like to also search "to" and other variables.

Lastly, I'd like this to have a trigger that is time-based (daily or weekly) and I'm still getting my head wrapped around triggers, so any help is really appreciated.

```
function myFunction() {
// Get the value in the cell D2 (which will have the email to check the latest interaction)
var ss = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('D2').getValue();

// Search the date of the last message of the search from the email in cell D1 and log it
var latestEmail = GmailApp.search('from:"'+ss+'"')[0].getLastMessageDate();
Logger.log(latestEmail);

// Print the date on the cell to the right
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('E2').setValue(latestEmail);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like that script to repeat row by row - now it only writes to Row 2

You will need to iterate ("loop") through your sheet's rows.

**Try this:**

```
function myFunction() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  const addresses = sheet.getRange(2, 4, sheet.getLastRow()-1).getValues().flat().filter(Boolean)

  for (let [index, address] of addresses.entries()) {
    const latestEmail = GmailApp.search(`from: ${address}`)[0].getLastMessageDate()
    sheet.getRange(index+2, 5).setValue(latestEmail);
  }

}
```

**Commented:**

```
function myFunction() {

  // Your sheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  // All cells in Column D (Column 4).
  const addresses = sheet.getRange(2, 4, sheet.getLastRow()-1).getValues().flat().filter(Boolean)

  // For each address in Column D... (While keeping track of the index)
  for (let [index, address] of addresses.entries()) {
    // Get the last message date from this address...
    const latestEmail = GmailApp.search(`from: ${address}`)[0].getLastMessageDate()
    // And set the adjacent cell to that date.
    sheet.getRange(index+2, 5).setValue(latestEmail);
    // "Index+2" because index starts at 0 and we started our range at row 2.
  }

}
```

> I'd also like to search for data in addition to "from". I'd like to also search "to" and other variables.

That can all be done using `GmailApp.search()`

> Lastly, I'd like this to have a trigger that is time-based (daily or weekly) and I'm still getting my head wrapped around triggers, so any help is really appreciated.

Couldn't be easier, see here:

- [Managing triggers manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

In your Script Editor, click the Triggers icon and then click the Add Trigger button.

You will be looking to choose this function, from event source: "Time-driven", and select when you would like it to run.

Comment: Many thanks for the help. I'm getting an error: TypeError: sheet.getRange(...) . flat is not a function

Comment: Do you have values in Column D of your sheet named "Sheet1" ?

Comment: Yes. Column D is the email address. Column E is the Last Message Date. Col A is First Name, Col B is Last Name, Col C is Organization. And the sheet has a header row.

Comment: I've updated the code for a more accurate range, please make sure you have at least two rows of data (First name, last name, organization, and email) under the header row. `addresses` should be: `const addresses = sheet.getRange(2, 4, sheet.getLastRow()-1).flat().filter(Boolean)`

Comment: Thanks for the continued help! I'm still getting the exact same "flat is not a function" error as before. It has to do with Line 6 of your code.

Comment: Ah, brain fart. We should probably get those values in that range huh? Updated code to include `.getValues()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244579/discussion-between-mark-and-newaza).